# What happens to a mapping when ad - bc = 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I know that when you have a mapping of the form $\frac{az + b}{cz + d}$, with $ad − bc \neq 0$, this gives you a Möbius transformation. But if $ad − bc = 0$, this gives you a constant mapping. I'm trying to figure out how to prove that latter statement - for a mapping $m(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$, if $ad − bc = 0$, then $m(z)$ is a constant map. I've been trying to think of the best way to prove this, but I keep getting stuck because I find myself making assumptions that potentially result in loss of generality (i.e. assuming $c$ and/or $a$ is $0$).

What is the best way to prove this? Should I maybe try a proof by contradiction? That is, assume that the mapping is not constant, and arriving at a contradiction?

Comment: Hint: a constant map is one that has zero derivative. Use the quotient rule.

Comment: Yup, take the derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ad-bc$ is the determinant of the following matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b\\
    c       & d\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Since the determinant is zero, the rows of this matrix are linearly dependent. So there is some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda c=a$ and $\lambda d=b$. And then:

$m(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\lambda\frac{cz+d}{cz+d}=\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by cases. Suppose $c=0$. Then $ad=bc$ implies $a=0$ or $d=0$. But for $d=0$, the map is well-defined, so $a=0$ and you're done. Similarly, if $a=0$, then $b$ or $c$ is $0$, and you're done.

If $a,c \neq 0$, then
$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d} = \frac{a(az+b)}{acz+ad} = \frac{a(az+b)}{acz+bc}= \frac ac \frac{az+b}{az+b} = \frac ac.$$

Answer (score 0):

You do have to worry about picky corner cases where you're dividing by zero. To be thorough you must rule out the case where both $c$ and $d$ are zero. With that case out of the way, assume $c\ne0$. This means you can divide by $c$, obtaining $b=\frac{ad}c$, which you then plug in:
$$
\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{az+\frac{ad}c}{c(z+\frac dc)}=\frac ac.$$
The remaining case $d\ne0$ is handled similarly.