# Invertibility condition for a Mobius transformation

Tags: group-theory

The Mobius transformation on $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is defined as $z\to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. I am trying to find the invertibility condition for this transform.

My attempt: Let $y=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. To find an inverse of $y$, we want to find $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4 \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\frac{e_1y+e_2}{e_3y+e_4}=z$. But if $y=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, then $\frac{dy-b}{-cy+a}=z$ and $d,-b,-c,a\in \mathbb{C}$. So consider the transformation : $z\to \frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$ and apply that to $y$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy-b}{-cy+a} &= \frac{d\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \right)-b}{-c\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)+a} \\
&= \frac{(ad-bc)z}{(ad-bc)} \\
&= z \quad\iff\quad ad-bc\neq 0
\end{align*}

Thus the invertibility condition for the Mobius transformation is $ad-bc\neq 0$. Is this the right way of arriving at the condition formally?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @LEY Thanks....

Comment: Personally, I am not convinced. You've correctly identified a map which inverts Mobius transformations for $ad-bc=0$. Does it follow that no inverse exists just because this guess fails for $ad-bc \neq 0$? I would try instead to show that such Mobius maps are not injective. (As shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3930700/685267).

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks, good to know that the transformation would be a constant when $ad-bc=0$. I don't think the map $z\to \frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$ inverts Mobius transformations for $ad-bc=0$. As shown above, $ad-bc$ cancels only when $ad-bc\neq 0$. So its invertible iff $ad-bc\neq 0$, right?

Comment: @Garfield As I said, I don't think it follows that there is no inverse (the "only if") just because that map fails to be an inverse.